# Is it possible to reinstall removed Android APIs?

Tags: android

Whilst trying to get one of the API demos to work I deleted the source files of said demo by mistake.
'No problem', I thought, 'I'll just reinstall the API level and get the source back.'
So after removing the 2.1 APIs from the Android SDK I found that it won't let me redownload and install them, they just don't appear.
So, does anyone know how I can get the SDK to forget that the 2.1 API has been installed and then removed, or do I have to remove the entire SDK and install again, including APIs.
Pretty standard insta

Many thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Are you the SDK manager in Eclipse?  Have you tried downloading the manager from their website again?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when trying to install API Demos for 2.3 over currently installed API Demos for 2.1. The console displayed the following, even when I manually removed it from the file system:

```
Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.

You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!

Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.apis' in a shell.

Launch canceled!
```

Unfortunately, it was impossible to uninstall the API Demos from the phone. The solution I came up with was to move all of the installed apps to SD card and factory reset the phone (**Settings -> Privacy -> Factory Data Reset**).

Answer (score 2):

I think i got the soln. Go to `Settings > Security > Device Administrators`. If you see Api Demo just un-check it and then try un-installing again.

NOTE: The instructions here are for Android 4.0.3 and 2.2.3. So should work on other platforms too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in the installed packages? since you can reinstall those> go to sdk> available packages>select all> install selected
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Apps -> ApiDemos.
Click Uninstall button